# Regex: Capture one or more groups if exists (Java)

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I want to capture groups matching a pattern where the input can contain this group one or more times.

Example:

```
input = 12361 randomstuff371 12 Mar 16 138more random381 stuff73f
```

I want to capture the "12 Mar 16".

From this I have easily used the regex:

```
pattern = (".*(\\d{2}\\s\\w+\\s\\d{2}).*");
```

However my trouble is that when the input can contain more than one of these groups, I'm not able to capture the subsequent matches.

Example:

```
input = randomstuff371 12 Mar 16 14 Jan 15 13 Feb 16 138more random381 stuff73f
```

Such that:

```
group 1 = 12 Mar 16
group 2 = 14 Jan 15
group 3 = 13 Feb 16
```

The number of these groups to match will always vary, and so I'm wondering if there is a regex that will work over inputs that contain 1 or more of these groups. I have tried:

```
pattern = (".*(\\d{2}\\s\\w+\\s\\d{2}\\s)+.*"); \\ Not sure about whitespace at the end
```

However It doesn't work. Is this more to do with how I'm storing these captured groups? I cannot predetermine the number of groups that I will need, especially since the regex needs to work over many of these inputs.

I feel as though I'm just better off capturing the entire segment of dates and handling it later with `matcher.find()` to count the number of groups that I require.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: That's because of the `.*` in the front and back. Don't do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will be easier to just match the specific pattern of yours and get the substrings as multiple matches obtained using `Matcher#find()`:

```
String s = "randomstuff371 12 Mar 16 14 Jan 15 13 Feb 16 138more random381 stuff73f";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{2}\\s\\w+\\s\\d{2}\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/nZHtSs) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pe7Z4A/1).

I added word boundaries to the pattern to make sure the pattern is matched as a whole word, but they may be omitted if your substrings are glued to another text.